# Not show the dialog with vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with a modal in Vue js.
To work with the correct styles, I installed vuetify, and the v-dialog component stopped working. The same was working without problems.

I have reviewed my code many times and found no differences from the previous version. Will it be a problem between versions of v-modal and vuetify?

An example:

```
<template>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
        <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
            <v-btn
            color="primary"
            dark
            v-bind="attrs"
            v-on="on"
            >
            Open Dialog
            </v-btn>
        </template>
        <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
            <span class="headline">User Profile</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
            <v-container>
                <v-row>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field label="Legal first name*" required></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field label="Legal middle name" hint="example of helper text only on focus"></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                    <v-text-field
                    label="Legal last name*"
                    hint="example of persistent helper text"
                    persistent-hint
                    required
                    ></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field label="Email*" required></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-text-field label="Password*" type="password" required></v-text-field>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-select
                    :items="['0-17', '18-29', '30-54', '54+']"
                    label="Age*"
                    required
                    ></v-select>
                </v-col>
                <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-autocomplete
                    :items="['Skiing', 'Ice hockey', 'Soccer', 'Basketball', 'Hockey', 'Reading', 'Writing', 'Coding', 'Basejump']"
                    label="Interests"
                    multiple
                    ></v-autocomplete>
                </v-col>
                </v-row>
            </v-container>
            <small>*indicates required field</small>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
            <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
        </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
        dialog: false
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Which version of Vuetify you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  export default {
        dialog: false,
  }
</script>
```

**dialog** is a data variable,so instead u should write it like this:-

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        dialog: false,
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. Yes, I have the code that way, only I made a mistake in copying it here.